# Match 2 people together from list randomly using one condition

Tags: excel, list, random, conditional-statements, formula

I am creating an excel sheet to randomly match 2 employees together from a list. Only criteria is that the employees cannot be apart of the same department.

I've created a formula that randomly matches people from a list, but have not been able to only match people if they are in different departments.

My current formula is:
    =INDEX($A:$A,RANDBETWEEN(1,COUNTA($A:$A)),1)

I expect the output to be: 
"John Doe IT" 
"Noah Body HR"

the current function can output: 
"John Doe IT"
"Jane Doe IT"

[This is an example of how I have the data setup (fake data in picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJ3iZ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your formula seems ok.. just need to add 2 more rules..

You could use an extra column to filter the department rule.. then do a sapeate index-randdmax on it.

put this on D2 : `=if(A2<>$I$4,VALUE(D1)+1,VALUE(D1))`

and drag till D27.

Then for the 2nd person formula.. do : `=INDEX($A:$A,MATCH(RANDBETWEEN(1,MAX(D:D)),D:D,0),1)`

Hope it helps.